# Generate marker with rails, ajax and Mapbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, mapbox

I want my users be able to generate markers on their own maps (on their profile page), when they create a post and enter a country. 
For now, I'm able to create a post, to choose a country, and save longitude and latitude using geocoder gem, but I am not able to generate the marker using ajax call, here is my codes :

users_controller.rb (show method):

```
 def show
     @post_all = @user.posts
      @geojson = Array.new()
      @post_all.each do |pos|
        @geojson << {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [pos.longitude, pos.latitude]
          },
          properties: {
            name: pos.title,
            address: pos.country,
            :'marker-color' => '#d9534f',
            :'marker-symbol' => 'circle',
            :'marker-size' => 'medium'
          }
        }
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @geojson }  # respond with the created JSON object
      end
  end
```

my application.js file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  L.mapbox.accessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoiYW50b3RvIiwiYSI6ImNpdm15YmNwNTAwMDUyb3FwbzlzeWluZHcifQ.r44fcNU5pnX3-mYYM495Fw";
  var map = L.mapbox.map('map').setView([48.856614, 2.3522219000000177], 4);
  var style = L.mapbox.styleLayer("mapbox://styles/antoto/civn0z51d00002ko4tmlch2zn").addTo(map);
  var marker = L.marker([48.856614, 2.3522219000000177], {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': '#d9534f'
      })
    })
    .bindPopup('hello')
    .addTo(map);
  map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/#{:id}/show.json',
    success: function(data) {
      geojson = $.parseJSON(data)
      console.log(data)
      map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson)
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data + ' error')
    }
  }); 
});
```

I think that there are problems in my URL in the ajax call, but when a create the geojson I don't know what url to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your application.js file is the issue here. You have this line `url: '/#{:id}/show.json',` where you are expecting(?) rails would interpolate your current user_id value for you...

Instead I think the better solution would be making a function called `grabUserData(user_id)`, and making the url line for the ajax call `url: '/' + user_id + '/show.json'`,...

Call this JS function from somewhere in your html where you have the user_id in question from rails dumped out to your page.

`var thisID = <%= current_user.id %>; grabUserData(thisID);`

Comment: Hey ! thank you for your answer ! I'm going to try that !

Comment: It work ! Thank you so much I appreciate your help !